# Density of states for arbitrary dispersion relation

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-of-states

If I have a 3D dispersion relation

$E=E(k_x, k_y, k_z)$ I have an equation for the density of states, which is

$D(E)=\frac{1}{\nabla_k E}\int\frac{dS}{(2\pi)^3}$

1) I am confused about the integral. What am I integrating over, exactly? It must have units of the $k$ vector, so it's a k-space integral, but what is the surface that is relevant?

3) Where does that equation come from, how is it derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deriving the desired equation for the density of states we are reminded that the surface which we are integrating over is a *surface of constant energy* in the reciprocal space which is denoted by $S(e)$, where $e$ is the 3-dimensional dispersion relation

we know that the number of states between the surfaces $S(e)$ and $S(e + de)$ is given by the integral. $$D(e)\, \mathrm{d}e = \int_{S(e)} \frac{\mathrm{d}S}{(2\pi )^3} \mathrm{d}q_\perp(\boldsymbol q)$$ if we linearly expand the dispersion relation $e$ as $e+\mathrm{d}e = e + |\nabla_\boldsymbol q e(\boldsymbol q)|\mathrm{d}q_\perp(\boldsymbol q)$ where $\boldsymbol q$ is a vector, $\mathrm{d}q_\perp (\boldsymbol q)$ is the perpendicular distance between the surfaces and $\mathrm{d}q_\perp(\boldsymbol q)= \frac {\mathrm{d}e}{|\nabla_\boldsymbol q e(\boldsymbol q)|}$. this leads to $$D(e) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3} \int_{S(e)} \frac {\mathrm{d}S}{|\nabla_\boldsymbol q e(\boldsymbol q)|}$$ 
which is the desired equation for the density of states.

Comment: One point of clarification: The initial expression for the number of states implies that each state occupies a q-space volume of $(2\pi)^3$. Why is that the case? For the case of a particle in a 3D box, for example, is the q-space volume not $\left(\frac{2\pi}{V}\right)^3$, or am I confusing variables here?

Comment: @KBriggs this is because in the equation for the total and partial density of states, we replace the summation over $\boldsymbol q$ by an integral of the form $\sum_\boldsymbol q \to \frac{V}{(2\pi)^3} \int \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol q$. for that reason there is a factor of $\frac{1}{V}$ behind the definition of $D(e) \mathrm{d}e$, and in the definition we multiply by $V$ to get rid of it.