# Density of states of non-rationally invariant dispersion relations (Energy bands)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

When one deals with a dispersion relation of the form
$$\epsilon(\vec{k})=\epsilon(|\vec{k}|)$$
then a simple transformation in polar/spherical coordinates is enough to find the density of states.

---

I read that for electrons in an **arbitrary dispersion relation** the DOS is given by
$$D(\epsilon)\propto\int_{\epsilon(\vec{k}=\textrm{const.})}\frac{dS_\epsilon}{|\nabla_\vec{k}\epsilon(\vec{k})|}$$
Where $dS_\epsilon$ is a surface element of the surface of constant energy. How does on proof this?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232008/density-of-states-for-arbitrary-dispersion-relation - I think the proof is outlined in the answer here

Comment: @Shrey yes! I didn't find this. I will mark my question as a duplicate